# How to concatenate string to comma-separated element in bash

Tags: bash

I am new to Bash coding. I would like to concatenate a string to each element of a comma-separated strings "array".

This is an example of what I have in mind:

```
s=a,b,c

# Here a function to concatenate the string "_string" to each of them.

# Expected result:

a_string,b_string,c_string
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way:

```
$ s=a,b,c
$ echo ${s//,/_string,}_string
a_string,b_string,c_string
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Answer (score 1):

Using a proper array is generally a much more robust solution. It allows the values to contain literal commas, whitespace, etc.

```
s=(a b c)
printf '%s\n' "${s[@]/%/_string}"
```

As suggested by chepner, you can use `IFS=","` to merge the result with commas.

```
(IFS=","; echo "${s[@]/%/_string}")
```

(The subshell is useful to keep the scope of the `IFS` reassignment from leaking to the current shell.)

Answer (score 0):

Simply, you could use a for loop

```bash
main() {
  local input='a,b,c'
  local append='_string'
  
  # create an 'output' variable that is empty
  local output=

  # convert the input into an array called 'items' (without the commas)
  IFS=',' read -ra items <<< "$input"

  # loop over each item in the array, and append whatever string we want, in this case, '_string'
  for item in "${items[@]}"; do
    output+="${item}${append},"
  done
  # in the loop, the comma was re-added back. now, we must remove the so there are only commas _in between_ elements
  output=${output%,}

  echo "$output"
}
main
```

Answer (score 0):

I've split it up in three steps:

1. Make it into an actual array.
2. Append `_string` to each element in the array using [Parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).
3. Turn it back into a scalar (for which I've made a function called `turn_array_into_scalar`).

```bash
#!/bin/bash

function turn_array_into_scalar() {
    local -n arr=$1   # -n makes `arr` a reference the array `s`
    local IFS=$2      # set the field separator to ,
    arr="${arr[*]}"   # "join" over IFS and assign it back to `arr`
}

s=a,b,c

# make it into an array by turning , into newline and reading into `s`
readarray -t s < <(tr , '\n' <<< "$s")

# append _string to each string in the array by using parameter expansion
s=( "${s[@]/%/_string}" )

# use the function to make it into a scalar again and join over ,
turn_array_into_scalar s ,

echo "$s"
```